# New lines in displaymath LaTeX

Tags: math, latex

I need to write the next formula in LaTeX, but I can't put it in multiple lines and with the right indentation for the subsequent lines, this is my code.

```latex
\begin{displaymath}
\pi_D^B(r) = \{z^{(|D|+1)}|\exists x \in r(z[D]=x[D])\wedge \\
             \forall y \in r (y[D]=z[D]\Rightarrow y[T]\subseteq z[T])\wedge \\
             \forall y \in z[T \exists y \in r (y[D]=z[D]\wedge t \in  y[T])\}
\end{displaymath}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since displaymath is not numbered perhaps you prefer the align* environment instead of align. Note, usually the & symbol is used before a relation symbol for the alignment.

For more information look at one of the documents listed here: [Mathematics with LaTeX](http://texblog.net/latex-link-archive/mathematics/).

Stefan

Answer (score 7):

Use the `align` environment from the `amsmath` package:

```
\begin{align}
 \pi_D^B(r) = &\{z^{(|D|+1)}|\exists x \in r(z[D]=x[D])\wedge \\
              &\forall y \in r (y[D]=z[D]\Rightarrow y[T]\subseteq z[T])\wedge \\
              &\forall y \in z[T \exists y \in r (y[D]=z[D]\wedge t \in  y[T])\}
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use eqnarray or better eqnarray* to avoid equation labels.

```
\begin{eqnarray*} 
\pi_D^B(r)  & = & \{z^{(|D|+1)}|\exists x \in r(z[D]=x[D])\wedge \\ 
            &   & \forall y \in r (y[D]=z[D]\Rightarrow y[T]\subseteq z[T])\wedge \\ 
            &   & \forall y \in z[T \exists y \in r (y[D]=z[D]\wedge t \in  y[T])\} 
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: Please avoid eqnarray. Just [google eqnarray](http://www.google.com/search?q=eqnarray) — several of the top results are about why you should avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Again, you could nest a `split` environment (from package [`amsmath`](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf)) inside your `displaymath`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \begin{split}
    \pi_D^B (r) = & \{z^{(|D|+1)} | \exists x \in r(z[D]=x[D]) \wedge \\
    & \forall y \in r (y[D]=z[D] \Rightarrow y[T] \subseteq z[T]) \wedge \\
    & \forall y \in z[T \exists y \in r (y[D]=z[D] \wedge t \in  y[T])\}
  \end{split}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output]

I think you should fix `z[T \exists` in the last line.